# Get bone rotation in pose mode using Python

Tags: python, scripting, armature, pose-mode

I want to get angles of joints in armature in pose mode, see the picture below. I tried to get local rotation of bones, but I can't find a way to do this.

[image]

I tried:

```
bone.rotation_euler()   # everytime returns [0, 0, 0] 
bone.matrix.to_euler()  # everytime returns some constant value e.g. [2, 0, 0]
```

I can rotate bone, but values don't change. How can I get actual rotations of the bone?

Also I find out a strange thing:

1. If bone has Rotation Constrait I can rotate it to constraint and it stops, but in Transform panel I see that angle is stil growing
2. If I use IK and move bone, location and translation in Transform window doesn't change.

Maybe this is relating to my problem. What is actually displays the Transform panel?

Comment: The `bone.rotation_euler` property is only used if the [`rotation_mode`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.rotation_mode) is set to use euler. The rotation from the matrix property should update with any rotation that is within constraint limits. Are you sure you are looking at the right bone? `context.active_bone` is not the same as `context.active_pose_bone`

Comment: I figured out that matrix works well. I was testing using console and values don't change when I move bone and call it, but when I add this code to `scene_update_post` handler it's works, but returns bone rotation in global coordinates. Thanks to your commetn, `rotation_euler` with `rotation_mode` is works. Can you write answer so I can accept it?

Comment: UPD: I test It with IK and `rotation_euler` doesn't change when IK-driven bone is moving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that bones have two representations within blender, the [`EditBone`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.EditBone.html) data represents it's static rest position within the armature while the [`PoseBone`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html) is the animated bone data that you would be moving around. The edit bones are stored in `obj.data.edit_bones` while the pose bones are in `obj.pose.bones`.

The [`rotation_mode`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.rotation_mode) value of a pose bone is used to switch between using `rotation_euler`, `rotation_axis_angle` or `rotation_quaternion`. These three rotation values can be seen in the bones properties and will show values without any constraints being applied. Note that euler values are stored as radians so you may want to use [`math.degrees()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.degrees) for the display value. Also the W in axis angle is radians.

The pose bones [`matrix`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix) value should give you the world position of the bone after constraints and drivers have been applied. You can get the bones euler rotation with [`bone.matrix.to_euler()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler). If using `bpy.context` to get the bone, you will find that `bpy.context.active_bone.matrix` will give you a matrix of zeros and ones while `bpy.context.active_pose_bone.matrix` will give you the matrix that you are after.

You can use a panel to watch the rotation of a bone -

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

class SimpleBoneAnglesPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Bone Angles"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        arm = context.scene.objects['Armature']
        bone = arm.pose.bones['Bone']

        mat = bone.matrix.to_euler()
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label(text='X: {:.3}'.format(degrees(mat.x)))
        row.label(text='Y: {:.3}'.format(degrees(mat.y)))
        row.label(text='Z: {:.3}'.format(degrees(mat.z)))

bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleBoneAnglesPanel)
```

Comment: great! helped me a lot!