# How to get Local bones rotation while in pose mode

Tags: python, scripting, pose-mode

I have a robot arm manipulator and I'd like to control it using blender as an intermediary. I already have the manipulator model rigged and would like to get the bones local rotation. I am able to get the world rotation but it is not the ideal in this case. After this, the idea is to send the value in degrees to the arduino so it can activate the servos.

Edit: I followed [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/get-bone-rotation-in-pose-mode-using-python) until this point