# Accessing Inverse Kinematics from python

Tags: animation, scripting, inverse-kinematics

I searched a lot about blender's Inverse Kinematics API, but I'm really confused right now.
So the goal of my project is to control a robot arm that has 4 degrees of freedom. So far, I managed to model a rig in blender, that has the same characteristics as the arm I'd like to control (see example below). I also successfully added Inverse Kinematics constraints to make it easier to draw shapes in the air (as you can guess by the screenshot).
[image: A blender 3D viewport with a robot arm-like rig]

Now the goal here is, in order to control this arm, I need to export the animation data as a CSV file, where each line contains data from one frame; and each column contains the angles of the joint in **local space**.

This is the code I have so far, since as a start I wanted to try some debugging of the values I might export later.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

class SimpleBoneAnglesPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Bone Angles"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

def draw(self, context):
    arm = context.scene.objects['Armature']
    self.drawInfo(arm,"Base")
    self.drawInfo(arm,"Shoulder")
    self.drawInfo(arm,"Elbow")
    self.drawInfo(arm,"Wrist vertical")
    
    
def drawInfo(self,armature,boneName):
    bone = armature.pose.bones[boneName]

    mat = bone.matrix.to_euler()
    self.layout.label(text=boneName)
    box = self.layout.box()
    box.label(text=f'X: {degrees(mat.x):.3f}')
    box.label(text=f'Y: {degrees(mat.y):.3f}')
    box.label(text=f'Z: {degrees(mat.z):.3f}')
```

Thanks to [this code snippet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/get-bone-rotation-in-pose-mode-using-python) for the inspiration, it really helped !

So far so good, you might think. As shown in the screenshot and in the above code, I can access the individual rotations of each bone on the x, y and z axis.

The problem is that each joint of my robot can only rotate on one axis. And even though the IK constraint seems to work perfectly fine visually, the numbers I get (see Bone Angles panel on the right of the screenshot), they change on Y **and** Z as the arm is moving. I need the rotation on Z axis for each of the joints (except for the base it's Y).

So my question is, how can I get the local rotation of each pose bone? It looks like the API has changed, and matrix_local doesn't exist anymore. Thank you for taking the time to read and maybe help me out, I hope I was clear and concise enough.