# Get local child bone rotation using Python

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, quaternion

I'm looking to get the local rotations of bones using Python, in other words given a parent and a child bone, the child bone's rotation off of the parent bone.

I saw this post:[Get bone rotation in pose mode using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/get-bone-rotation-in-pose-mode-using-python)

But I'm under the impression that this gives the world rotation? Any explanations are appreciated, thank you!

[image: skeleton]

Answer (score 3):

`pose_bone.matrix` is the transform from bone-local-space to *armature-space* (not world-space). It is the *real* transform, after constraints, drivers, etc. are applied.

So you can get the transform relative to the bone's parent by first transforming into armature space with `pbone.matrix`, then transforming from armature space in `pbone.parent`'s space with `pbone.parent.matrix.inverted()`.

```
for pbone in ob.pose.bones:
    m = pbone.matrix
    if pbone.parent:
        m = pbone.parent.matrix.inverted() @ m
    print(pbone.name, m)
```

Note that the matrix `m` might not be a pure rotation matrix in general (although for your screenshot it looks like it will be).

Also note that this won't work if you have non-invertible matrices. Avoid scaling bones to 0.