# Can't get final rotation from bone that is rotated

Tags: armature

[image]

This bone is rotated, but no rotation is in the outliner, when I query the bone rotation I get the identity matrix. I can't seem to get the propoer rotation values, I have tried the matrix that takes in constraints and drivers as well as other matrices, and I have tried switching to other spaces too.

Comment: Do these posts answer your question?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/get-bone-rotation-in-pose-mode-using-python
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244806/get-local-child-bone-rotation-using-python

Comment: The first one is about the orientation of joints which I think I can get through getMatrixfromAxisAngle or something. I get the axis and angle from roll and vector in the edit bones. I'm gonna do some tests with the second one. Will get back on that.

Comment: The second didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation of all bones can be retrieved as shown below.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

obj = bpy.context.object 

if obj.type == "ARMATURE":
    for bone in obj.pose.bones:
        translation, rotation, scale = mathutils.Matrix(bone.matrix).decompose()
        print(f"{bone.name}: {rotation}")
```

While in pose mode it is also possible to get the rotation of the currently selected bone through:

```
import bpy
import mathutils

obj = bpy.context.object

if obj.type == "ARMATURE" and obj.mode == "POSE":
    bone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
    translation, rotation, scale = mathutils.Matrix(bone.matrix).decompose()
    print(f"{bone.name}: {rotation}")
```