# How to get global rotation of a bone with respect to global planes of axis via python?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, transforms

I'm simply trying to find the global rotation of a bone in pose mode using python

i.e. what angle a bone makes with the global axis?

[image]

The closest I've come is:

```
for pb in context.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object:
    
    
    pb_world_matrix=armature.matrix_world @ pb.matrix
    loc, rot, scale = pb_world_matrix.decompose()
    rot= rot.to_euler();
    
    print(pb.name,"x=",math.degrees(rot.x),"y=",math.degrees(rot.y),"z=",math.degrees(rot.z))
```

**Edit:**
let me explain what I mean with an example:
[image]

As you can see in the gif above, initially the angles are:

```
x_glob= 0deg
y_glob= 0deg
z_glob= 0deg
```

then I first rotate it by `38deg` on global y orientation then I rotate by `41.3deg` on global x orientation so the final output should be:

```
x_glob= 41.3deg
y_glob= 38deg
z_glob= 0deg
```

I think a better way of looking at the problem is finding the angle made with the planes of global axis (I couldn't find the wording to phrase it till now)

Comment: In your example you don't show any parenting, so bone's local rotation is also global rotation... Except Y and Z are swapped.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I didn't want to make the question too complex & confusing so I didn't add that part, but when I meant globally I meant the rotation regardless of parenting

Answer (score 2):

I had a little look into it but I'm not an expert. Discovered you can get the matrix world of the selected bone using `pb_mw = pb.matrix`. Then using `pb_mw.to_euler()` you can obtain the euler rotation from the matrix. The only catch seemed to be that a bone at rest position in the interface (x,y,z rotation at 0 degrees in the UI) is actually at 90 degrees on the x axis in the world matrix. Happy for further input on this.

```py
import bpy
from math import degrees

context = bpy.context

for pb in context.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object:
    
    pb_mw = pb.matrix
    pb_rot = pb_mw.to_euler()
    
    print(f"pb matrix world: {pb_mw}")
    print(f"x rotation: {degrees(pb_rot.x) - 90}")
    print(f"y rotation: {degrees(pb_rot.y)}")
    print(f"z rotation: {degrees(pb_rot.z)}")

# Test on empty  
# empty = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
# empty.matrix_world = pb_mw
```

Edit: related answer here... [Get bone rotation in pose mode using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/get-bone-rotation-in-pose-mode-using-python?rq=1)

Comment: I don't see how this gives you the global rotation?

Comment: The `pb.matrix` is the matrix world of the bone which has the global rotation in it... you simply use `.to_euler()` to extract just the rotation part of it.

Comment: that does not give me the global rotation `i.e. what angle a bone makes with the global axis?`

Comment: @cakelover you might need give some more details about what angle you are trying to calculate exactly, because the matrix world does give the global rotation as far as I can see?

Comment: I've added an example, does that clear it up?

Comment: Yes, doing some more testing I can see that the UI rotations in pose mode are different to the matrix world rotations in python which is confusing... bones seem to have an up axis of Y in pose mode (instead of Z, not sure why this is), so the rotations in the UI are calculated different... but the matrix world rotations are correct for the global world space which you can see when it's applied to an empty.

Comment: Also keep in mind parenting can modify head/tail positions of bones in Edit Mode.

Comment: If you want just the global rotations with Z-up (eg. to apply to an object) than you can calculate them this way... if you want the global rotations relative to the bones Y-up orientation I'm not sure how to convert it sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

Why? It is because you have converted rotation from quaternions to Euler angles. That's basically means, that you have dozens of variants to have the same rotation using Eulers. Let me show the example:

Here are 2 figures rotated same way, but, first one has rotation 90,90,0:

[image]

second 180, 90, 90

[image]

As you see, you can't get initial transforms of the object.

Using `rot.to_euler();` gives you one of the variants. But you may get something different, that you have expected.

Of course, you have some initial rotation values, but it's hard to convert them to global without using a transform matrix. And when you put values in the matrix, there is no way to return them back unchanged.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case, that's why I modified the question and added planes, finding the rotation with respect to planes would achieve what I'm looking for, sorry for phrasing the question poorly initially

Comment: It's not really hard, you need to iterate over parents and rotate by negated Euler rotation components in reversed order.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'm not sure, you have missed possible scaling.

Comment: @Crantisz scaling won't affect rotation, unless of course I don't understand the OP.

Comment: Uniform maybe yes, but not uniform affects

Comment: Can you show an example of scale affecting rotation? 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady https://www.screenpresso.com/=aWOgg

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import math
from mathutils import Matrix,Vector

unit_x=Vector((1.0,0.0,0.0))
unit_y=Vector((0.0,1.0,0.0))
unit_z=Vector((0.0,0.0,1.0))

for pb in context.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object:
    
    axis, roll = pb.bone.AxisRollFromMatrix(pb.matrix.to_3x3(), axis=pb.y_axis)

    x_angle=Vector((pb.vector.x,0,pb.vector.z)).angle(unit_x) #angle made with x plane
    y_angle=Vector((0,pb.vector.y,pb.vector.z)).angle(unit_y) #angle made with y plane
    z_angle=Vector((pb.vector.x,0,pb.vector.z)).angle(unit_z) #angle made with z plane
    
    print("angle with plane x:",math.degrees(x_angle))
    print("angle with plane y:",math.degrees(y_angle))
    print("angle with plane z:",math.degrees(z_angle))
    print("self roll:",math.degrees(roll))
```

added a little roll bonus in there